# Rewrite without changing URL in same domain using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Two URLs 
NEW URL :

> http://host.ip.address/nl/business/producten-en-diensten/gsm-en-smartphones/samsung-galaxy-j1-2016-zwart

OLD URL :

> http://host.ip.address/nl/producten-en-diensten/gsm-en-smartphones/samsung-galaxy-j1-2016-zwart

when in request NEW URL from browser it should retrieve content from OLD URL and the URL should not change in browser.
I have tried the below rule in .htaccess it is rewriting and redirecting to the OLD URL which should not do in my case

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (^|.*?/)nl/business/(.*)$ /$1nl/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do a redirect and keep the original URL in the address bar." This is because a redirect, by definition, involves telling the browser to ask for the requested resource at a different URL. So the browser updates its address bar and uses the new URL.

The simplest way would be use a rewrite, not a redirect. An internal rewrite simply serves content from a local file-path that is different from the requested local URL-path.

You can use something easy like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule nl/producten-en-diensten/gsm-en-smartphones/samsung-galaxy-j1-2016-zwart nl/business/producten-en-diensten/gsm-en-smartphones/samsung-galaxy-j1-2016-zwart
```

You may need to also add

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```